# Python: My for loop doesnt work. Only checks first element

Tags: python, for-loop

I am still pretty new to python and I have a problem with my code.

It seems like my loop isn't looping through the entire network. The network is a list where each element is a dictionary for a person, it tells the name of the person, which games it likes, and who it is connected to.
I've tested the loop by putting a print line in the loop, and it only shows the first element than. So because of this my outcome is only right if it's about the first element in my network.

So if I `print add_connection(network, "John", "Mercedes")` I get the updated network with the connection added, which is what I expect, so this is good. But if I `print add_connection(network, "Bryant", "John")` I expect to get the updated network again but instead it returns network unchanged. Here is my code:

```
network = [{'Games': ['The Movie: The Game', 'The Legend of Corgi', 'Dinosaur Diner'], 'Connected': ['Bryant', 'Debra', 'Walter'], 'Name': 'John'}, {'Games': ['City Comptroller: The Fiscal Dilemma', 'Super Mushroom Man'], 'Connected': ['Olive', 'Ollie', 'Freda', 'Mercedes'], 'Name': 'Bryant'}, {'Games': ['The Legend of Corgi', 'Pirates in Java Island', 'Seahorse Adventures'], 'Connected': ['Walter', 'Robin', 'Bryant'], 'Name': 'Mercedes'}]


def add_connection(network, user_A, user_B):
    for eachPerson in network:
        if user_A == eachPerson["Name"]:
            exists = False
            for connection in eachPerson["Connected"]:
                if connection == user_B:
                    exists = True
            if exists == False:
                eachPerson["Connected"].append(user_B)
                return network
    return "network unchanged"

print add_connection(network, "John", "Mercedes")
print add_connection(network, "Bryant", "John")
```

Does anyone know what i've done wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Do you know that your example input is all a single line? The line separator enables you to write the string on multiple lines but it is just a single line. You should probably make a multiline string, and split on newlines.

Comment: This is a lot of code so there is a lot to go through to figure out what you're trying to do and what the issue is. You'll probably have better luck getting answers if you produce a minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide an example scenario pinpointing **exactly** the problem you are facing, that would help people understand the question better.

Comment: Yes i do know the example input is in one line. This is given to me. The problem is that I expect that if i print `add_connection(create_data_structure(example_input), "Bryant", "John")` it  should return the network with the new connection added instead it returns: network unchanged. It seems to do that because it doesn't loop through the network, it only checks the first person. So if i print `add_connection(create_data_structure(example_input), "John", "Mercedes")` it does work because John is the first person in the network list.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stepping through this with a debugger? My python is a bit rusty but from the looks of it, the method could terminate after the first iteration if `eachPerson["Connected"]` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases that this will terminate.

```
if check_in_Network(network, user_A, user_B) == False:
```

Can be written as (don't camelcase function names):

```
if not check_in_network(network, user_A, user_B):
```

And the second is if userA is in the network, and does not have a connection with userB. Does this sound right? You can step through your code to see it executing using:

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

Add the above on the start of your function.
The commands are here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands

Most of the time, n (next), s (step), r (return) and c (continue) is all you need.